# Adding the word "Chap" before the chapters numbers in the TOC

Tags: macros, table-of-contents

I'm using the book class and I need to add the word "Chap" before the chapters numbers in the TOC. Please keep in mind that the "Chap" should only appear before my chapters numbers, not before starred chapters titles, the Index, appendices or anything similar in the TOC.
By the way, I prefer to use the book class codes rather than to use packages.
Can anybode help me accomplish this?
Here is a minimal example:
‎

```
\documentclass{book}‎
‎\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}‎‎
‎\begin{document}‎‎
‎\tableofcontents‎‎
‎\chapter{One‎}‎‎
‎\chapter{Two‎}‎‎‎‎
‎\section{B‎la}‎‎
‎\chapter*{B‎la bla}
‎\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{bla‎ ‎bla}‎‎
‎\appendix‎‎
‎\chapter{App one}‎
‎\begin{thebibliography}{99}‎‎
‎\bibitem{bla‎}‎
‎bla‎
‎\end{thebibliography}‎‎‎             
‎\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make a copy of `\@chapter` and then redefine `\@chapter` to add the word "Chap"; from the point on where the word must not appear, restore the original meaning of `\@chapter`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\let\orig@chapter\@chapter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {Chap~\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\frontmatter
\chapter{Acknowledgements}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}

\makeatletter
\let\@chapter\orig@chapter
\makeatother
\appendix
\chapter{Test Appendix One}

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting ToC:

[image]

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina How to use your code in `\documentclass{report}`?

Comment: @minthao_2011 Please feel free to open a follow-up question.