# Name "Chapter" is not showed in the table of the content

Tags: table-of-contents

In my LaTeX code I add the line

```
\tableofcontents
```

And begging of each chapter i have these lines.

```
\renewcommand{\vspace}[2]{}\chapter{ }
{\huge\bf Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
```

When i compile my code it shows

```
1                                                                                 5
    Introduction                                                                  5
        1.1 Overview . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    5
2                                                                                 6
    Computing                                                                     6
        2.1 Computing type . . . . .... . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 6
```

Like this,

But I want to get the "Chapter" name to in front of the number like this.

```
Chapter 1 
    Introduction 
        1.1 Overview . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .5
Chapter 2 
    Computing 
        2.1 Computing type . .  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 6
```

How can I do that?

Comment: use the `tocloft` package (or the `memoir` class) it has featues to add such names

Comment: I tried it but it end up with same result.

Comment: @Team, how was the code for trying that?

Comment: i just put the 
\usepackage{tocloft}
to the code

Comment: Thanks all i got it by adding
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\large \chaptername~}

Comment: ***Never*** redefine `\vspace`!

Comment: Hmm, seems I'm mistaken, `tocloft` does not provide the naming prefix that `memoir` provide

Comment: 99.9% related: [Adding the word “Chap” before the chapters numbers in the ToC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60469/5764)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `tocloft` package to do this: a redefinition of `\cftchappresnum` allows to add `\chaptername` before the sectional unit number (this requires increasing the length `\cftchapnumwidth`). Redefining `\cftchapaftersnumb` you can add a line break after the sectional number and some negative horizontal spacing to achieve the desired alignment. A little example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newlength\mylen
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~}
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnumb{\\*\hspace*{-\mylen}}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylen}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Overview}
\chapter{Computing}
\section{Computing type}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **egreg** points out in his comment, it is *not* a good idea to redefine `\vspace`. If you want to redefine the formatting for the sectional units and you are using a standard document class, you can use the `titlesec` package.