# How can I add the word "Chap" before the chapters numbers in the Toc in class report?

Tags: table-of-contents

At here [Adding the word "Chap" before the chapters numbers in the TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60469/adding-the-word-chap-before-the-chapters-numbers-in-the-toc/60482?noredirect=1#comment365720_60482)
the word `Chapter` added in `\documentclass{book}`. Now I want to use them in `\documentclass{report}`. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand the error. Can you please mention the code? right now in my thesis, \section are used for every chapter which displays chapter like 1 introduction, 2 literature. I'm using this \documentclass[12pt, chapterprefix]{article} \usepackage[a4paper, margin=20mm]{geometry}?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the modification for the `report` class (basically, it's the same code but suppressing the conditional test for the `\frontmatter`); I defined two commands `\AddChap` and `\SuppChap` to activate (deactivate, resp.) the addition:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\let\orig@chapter\@chapter
\newcommand\SuppChap{%
  \let\@chapter\orig@chapter}
\newcommand\AddChap{%
\def\@chapter[##1]##2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {Chap~\protect\numberline{\thechapter}##1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{##1}%
                       \fi
                    \chaptermark{##1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{##2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{##2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Acknowledgements}

\AddChap
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}

\SuppChap
\appendix
\chapter{Test Appendix One}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am a Vietnamese. If I use `\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}`. Can I repair the "Chap" into the "Chương" or "Chuong"?

Comment: How Can add the word `Index` in `\tableofcontents`?

Answer (score 8):

A much simpler solution with the `tocloft` package.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newlength\mylength

\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chap~}
\settowidth\mylength{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Intro}

\chapter{Test}

\end{document}
```

Output (ToC):

[image]

---

### EDIT

If you want to add the word "Appendix" instead of "Chap" for your appendices, you can load the package `etoolbox` and add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\apptocmd{\appendix}
  {\addtocontents{toc}{%  
   \protect\addtolength\protect\cftchapnumwidth{-\mylength}%
   \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{Appendix~}%
   \protect\settowidth\mylength{\bfseries\protect\cftchappresnum\protect\cftchapaftersnum}%
   \protect\addtolength\protect\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength}}%
  }{}{}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\appendix}
  {\addtocontents{toc}{%  
   \protect\addtolength\protect\cftchapnumwidth{-\mylength}%
   \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{Appendix~}%
   \protect\settowidth\mylength{\bfseries\protect\cftchappresnum\protect\cftchapaftersnum}%
   \protect\addtolength\protect\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength}}%
  }{}{}

\newlength\mylength

\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chap~}
\settowidth\mylength{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylength}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Intro}

\chapter{Test}

\appendix

\chapter{Conclusions}

\end{document}
```

Output (ToC):

[image]

Comment: If I want to add the word "Appendix" in Toc, how must I do?

Comment: @minthao_2011 Do you have something like `\chapter*{appendix}` in your document?

Comment: No. I have some appendices.

Comment: @minthao_2011 Are you saying that you want to insert the word `Appendix` instead of `Chap` for your appendices?

Comment: Yes. I want so.

Comment: @minthao_2011 I've edited the answer.

Comment: @Karloeller How to use the `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`
`\pagestyle{fancyplain}`  
`\pagestyle{fancy}` in your code?

Comment: @minthao_2011 What do you mean?

Comment: @ karlkoeller How can I add the dot (.) after the Chap in Toc?

Comment: @minthao_2011 Sorry for the late reply. Simply change the definition to `\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chap.~}` if you want the dot before the number or add `\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}` if you want it after the number.