# How do i add chapter numbers in table of contents like chapter 1 introduction

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, geometry

How do I add chapter numbers to the table of contents, like chapter 1 introduction? I'm using the geometry package. It shows "1 introduction" i want to show it like "Chapter 1 Introduction".

Comment: There are many similar questions in this site such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/how-can-i-add-the-word-chap-before-the-chapters-numbers-in-the-toc-in-class-re

Comment: I don't understand the error. Can you please mention the code? right now in my thesis, \section are used for every chapter which displays chapter like 1 introduction, 2 literature. I'm using this \documentclass[12pt, chapterprefix]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=20mm]{geometry}

Comment: If you are using a specific thesis class, please show the code of the `.cls` file.

Comment: there is no .cls file its all .tex

Comment: Anyway, provide all the source files that can reproduce your problem. Only in this way can you get quicker help from other community members.

Comment: A good answer to your question requires knowledge of the LaTeX document class you employ; do please reveal this piece of information. Incidentally, there appears to be a disconnect between the title and the content of your query: Do you want to add (a) a *number* (say, "1") or (b) the *string* "Chapter" (as a prefix to the chapter number)? Please clarify.

Comment: To keep us all from guessing, please follow these steps to post a meaningful code, which shows your problem: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 . Half of the comments could have been avoided, which tried just to clarify this. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! You should be using `book` or `report` if you have chapters. Then you can say `\chapter{}`. That won't necessarily get you the output you want, but it will provide a basis for doing so. Hard to say more without code.