# Same style of chapter in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, titlesec

I want to have the same styles in titleformat command and ToC. How can I do this? I want to see "CHAPTER 1. SOME TITLE" in ToC in the example below:

```
\documentclass{extreport}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries\filcenter}{CHAPTER \thechapter. }{0mm}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{SOME TITLE}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: ToC]
[image: Title]

Comment: See the answer to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60469/adding-the-word-chap-before-the-chapters-numbers-in-the-toc).

Comment: Why I cant do the same by titlesec package? And I want to do it not for only chapter. (section, subsection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with `titlesec`, you can use `titletoc` to format the entries of the table of contents.

[image]

```
\documentclass{extreport}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\filcenter}{CHAPTER \thechapter. }{0mm}{}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0mm]{\bfseries}{CHAPTER \thecontentslabel. }{}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{SOME TITLE}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

For more details, see the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) of `titletoc`, section 6.

Comment: Thank you! I wrote `{CHAPTER \thechapter. }` and got "CHAPTER 0". I didn't know about `\thecontentslabel`.